# ERROR whitelist rejection on iOS using Cordova 5

Tags: ios, cordova

I've been using cordova for almost 3 years, and used to add the following line in config.xml to whitelist all resources.

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Today, I upgraded to cordova 5, and I've been getting a lot of the following error

```
ERROR whitelist rejection: url='example.com'
```

I installed cordova-plugin-whitelist, and updated my config.xml with the following 3 lines

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

And added the following meta tag to my index.html twice, once with gap and another without it

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

and nothing happened! still getting the "ERROR whitelist rejection" in Xcode console!

Comment: Did you found a solution for this? Then please answer your own question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As usual, I removed all platforms and plugins, re-added them again and everything worked fine!

Comment: same to me...i deleted the platforms folder from the ionic project folder, re added the platform and works fine in iOS